# Service loses it's intent when it is restarted by system

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am starting a `Service` like this:

```
Intent intentService = new Intent(getActivity(), ACNotificationService.class);
intentService.putExtra("ACReservation", reservationActivity.acReservation);
getActivity().startService(intentService);
```

And this is my `Service` class:

```
/*
Variables
 */

private NotificationManager notificationManager;

private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

private static int NOTIFICATION_COUNTDOWN = 0;
private static int NOTIFICATION_RANOUT = 1;

private ACReservation acReservation;

/*
Callbacks
 */

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Initialize variables
    notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Register EventBus
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // Get reservation data from extras
    if (acReservation == null) {
        acReservation = (ACReservation) intent.getExtras().get("ACReservation");
    }

    // Start timer
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(acReservation.getRemainingMilliseconds(), 100) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // Update/Show notification
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_COUNTDOWN, createReservationActiveNotification((int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // Clear notifications
            notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_COUNTDOWN);

            // Stop service
            stopSelf();
        }
    }.start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

/*
Methods
 */

public Notification createReservationActiveNotification(int expInMinutes) {
    Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    notification.setContentTitle("Reservation");
    notification.setContentText("Your reservation expires in " + expInMinutes + " minutes");
    notification.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.car_icon);
    notification.setOngoing(true);
    notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    notification.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
    return notification.build();
}

public void onEvent(ACEventBusButtonClick buttonClick) {
    if (buttonClick.getButtonAction() != null) {
        if (buttonClick.getButtonAction().equals(ACEventBusButtonClick.BUTTON_CANCEL_RESERVATION)) {
            notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_COUNTDOWN);
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty simple. I take the object out of `Intent` and use it to calculate milliseconds. Then I start a new `CountDownTimer` which keeps updating a `Notification`.

It works as it should until the `Service` is restarted by system. It loses it's `Intent` extra data and it crashes at this line of code when it is restarted:

```
if (acReservation == null) {
    acReservation = (ACReservation) intent.getExtras().get("ACReservation");
}
```

Log says it crashes because `Intent` is `null`. So I am calling `getExtras()` on a null object when `Service` is restarted.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) from `onStartCommand()` instead of the super call which returns the default value.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)

Comment: Shouldn't this be the default behaviour? I mean, why wouldn't someone want to get the intent redelivered? Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: The doc says "for backwards compatibility", which is a pretty big club and mean almost anything. It all really depends on the semantics of your `Service`. Maybe you have a half-finished service that saves state some other way and wants to pick up where it has left, and you could use a null check on the delivered intent to determine if it's a new invocation or you have to pick up the old one. Maybe that's the way all services worked before the various flags were introduced in api level 5.